# for what integer $m,n,d$: $\sum_{k=1}^r k^n= \left(\sum_{k=1}^r k^d\right)^m$?

Tags: number-theory, summation

for what integer $m,n,d$: $$\sum_{k=1}^r k^n=\left(\sum_{k=1}^r k^d\right)^m\text{ ?}$$

I know that $$\sum_{k=1}^r k^3= \left(\sum_{k=1}^r k^1\right)^2$$

but is there any general rule ?and how to prove it ?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that as $r\to\infty$ we have
$$
  \frac{1}{r^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^r k^n \to \int_0^1 x^n\,dx = \frac{1}{n+1}
$$
and
$$
  \frac{1}{r^{(d+1)m}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^r k^d\right)^m \to \left(\int_0^1 x^d\,dx\right)^m=\frac{1}{(d+1)^m}.
$$
Thus as necessary conditions we must have
$$
  n+1 = (d+1)m = (d+1)^m.
$$
For $m>1$ this equation has unique solution $d=1$, $m=2$, $n=3$.

The above solution works only for nonnegative $n,d$. If either $n$ or $d$ is negative they both must be, and we can argue alternatively as follows. By putting $r=2$ we get
$$
  1+2^n = (1 + 2^d)^m = 1 + 2^{dm} + \text{positive integer multiple of $2^{d(m-1)}$},
$$
which is impossible.